# How to create sub strings from raw bar code data with variable delimiter's/ delimiter order

Tags: c#, substring

I need to be able to pull sub strings out of a large string based on data identifiers. What is the proper method to pull specific strings of data?

I'll start with the fact I am a co-op student/ intern so go easy on me.

I am writing a program for a stand alone hand held computer scanner that will store the scanned data internally and transfer it to a computer when docked. (No RF or wireless on this particular site). I can scan a bar code and see the complete string of data no problem, its when I attempt to separate the data string into its variable parts (Part #, vender ID, Date, etc) that I cant get past. I can split the string based on each of the identifiers into a string array but im not sure how to call on the specific data sets based on the prefix data identifier so i can place the needed information into a data grid or export to excel properly.

Ultimately I would like to be able to define all of the different data identifiers( and there are a lot) and have my program go through each scan and pick out the needed information. Since this is a learning experience for me, Im not asking for someone to write it for me but point me in the right direction :)

Comment: Splitting a string is not a problem, given what those identifiers are. Without telling us what those are it's hard to answer. So how do you identify `PartNo`, `Vendor ID`, `Date` etc from the string? What are the constraints? If you tell us that, we can start from there.

Answer (score 0):

If the identifiers are always the same between scans, I'd use string.Split

```
string[] stringArray = scannedString.Split(new string[]{"identifier1", "identifier2"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive found that using regex has been the best solution.

The only problem I have now is that the my expressions can contain overlapping values. such as in the following code matching to:

[)>6P2427488**5Q641JUN6**31170227A0000027L20LA6-98721L54321 ZESKG11556D5-13-19 7:48 AM0366D190513MAY05-13-19011BKLT32147Q76GT2SDELNOTEPUSINV

The quantity is only 64 but my expression is adding the "1" from the 1JUN expression to its value, which is no good. So if anyone has any advice for preventing overlapping expressions? Otherwise Ill be getting learneded on regex methods.

//Define "Showmatch" and what to do when matches found
        public void showMatch(string text, string expr, TextBox tb, Label lbl) 
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(expr);
            Match match = regex.Match(text);

```
        if (match.Success)
        {
            tb.Text = match.Value;            
        }
        else
        {
            tb.Text = "No Data Found";                
        }

    }



    //Set Regular Expression Parameters 
    DateTime scan_Date = DateTime.Today;
    string part_Param = "(P)[0-9-]+";
    string serial_Param = "S[0-9-]+";  
    string duns_Param = "(1JUN)[0-9]+";
    string quant_Param = "Q[0-9]+"; 
    string unknown_Param = "20L-B[a-zA-Z0-9]";



    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Pop up window to select data source document
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Text Documents(*.txt)|*.txt", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = true })

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Read Text Document From scanner
                string[] raw_data = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);

                string mod_data = string.Join("", raw_data);

                textBox1.Text = (mod_data);
                tbScanDate.Text = scan_Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");

                showMatch(mod_data, part_Param, tbPartNumber, lblPartNumber);
                showMatch(mod_data, serial_Param, tbSerialNumber, lblSerialNumber);
                showMatch(mod_data, duns_Param, tbDunsNumber, lblDunsNumber);
                showMatch(mod_data, quant_Param, tbQuantity, lblQuantity);
                showMatch(mod_data, unknown_Param, tbOther, lblOther);



            }
```